# how to solve this media query conflict?

Tags: html, css

Here am using this two media query ,as I read ,**First MediaQuery** would affect background-color if size of screen size is equal or less then 340px ,where as **2nd MediaQuery** would effect if size of screen is less then or equal to 360px...

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
        #arf_recaptcha_hruwj8 iframe {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        #arf_recaptcha_hruwj8 iframe {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
```

What i thought is if size is under 340px,**1st query** would effect and because we are under 340px now. not in 360px.But instead of becoming blue ,it remain red only.
1.Could You please explain me this confusion ?

2.How to write media query so that when its **between 341px and 360px** It should be **red** and when **<=** 340px i have to be **blue**.

Comment: the first one is useless here ... there is no special precedence for media ... the logic apply to the selectors and their order, the media query is like an *if* statement to tell if we consider the selector or not

Comment: Also, you seem to be having an extra parenthesis } in your code

Comment: so last one will effect .

Comment: yes last one IF it's considered and under 340px both are considered so the last one will win

Answer (score 2):

Just swipe your media query and check it will work for sure.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
     iframe {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
    iframe {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: it also works initially .. this will simply make it works differently. The important part (missing here) is why and how it works

Comment: because correct ordering is important in media query. sequence should be high to low. e.g 1024 960 360 340

Comment: since it's important you need to explain it ;) .. *just swipe* is not enough to understand

Answer (score 0):

It's about precedence(CSS Specificity). Last one always applies if you are applying using same selector. As It reads code/file from top to bottom.

```
#idid{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        #idid {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
        #idid {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
```

JSBin link: [JSBin LInk](https://jsbin.com/rebumasala/edit)

You can also try css specificity here: [CSS Specificity checker](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) and (min-width: 340px)
 {
  body {
        background-color:red ;

}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 339px) {
  body {
        background-color: blue;

}
```

It's about precedence media query. Last one always applies if you are applying using same selector. swipe the code itz works perfectly